# What is this regex type?

Tags: ruby

What is the type of this?

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

It's a constant and I would assume it's a string, but it's not quoted...
If it's a string-like thing why is there no quotes?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: it's just a Regexp. More can be found here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html

Comment: Whats the data type of the regex itself

Comment: So rails knows its a Regex data type from the / / encapsulating slashes?

Comment: it's not the rails type but the one of the core types that come with ruby. You may think of this that way: when ruby parser is processing the `VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i` line it know that what you want to achieve is the Regexp. You could write `Regexp.new(...)` but for your convenience it's possible to use shorter version.

Comment: Regexp is just another Ruby class with that syntax. The same way you create a String object writing `This is a string`, you create a Regexp object writing `/\d{4}/`, for example

Answer (score 2):

It's a [`Regexp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html), just like you already said in the subject line of your question.